# PDO objects across classes

Tags: php, class, function, object, pdo

I'm looking for some feedback on the following:

I currently have two classes, which are being used in my PHP application.

A database connection class, which is currently using `MySQL` (but switching to `PDO`).

Another class (with several functions) which requires database functionality.

I'm looking for the best way to design this, I've read up on singletons (with very mixed reviews), read examples where objects were simply declared as `new` for each method (class functions), and examples where the connection was assigned to a private variable as part of a `__constructor` method for each class (then referenced with `$this->`).

So, how does everyone else do it? I hope you will be kind enough to perhaps give an example, and also welcome opinions on what others have read please.

I've got 2 separate classes, in two separate files. I want to keep clean code, reduce unnecessary overhead on the DB, and avoid anything that could be considered outdated (such as globals).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Database` class, which is responsible for connecting, should **be the one connecting to the database, creating the new PDO instance, and saving it to a field in itself**.

```
class Database {
    private $pdo;
    public __construct() {
        $this->pdo = new PDO(...);
    }
}
```

The second class, *which doesn't care where the DB connection is from, it just needs it to work* should be **injected with the `Database` class**:

```
class WorkerClass {
    private $db;
    public __construct(Database $db) {
        $this->db = $db;
    }
}
```

Comment: And that is what I have started doing in my gitHub MVC :-) @ircmaxell would be proud :-)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, this looks like a good option. I'll be honest I'm new to the __construct magic method, and as such I'm not 100% on what passing the Database class and $db variable is doing - would you care to explain, please?

Comment: Sure, in order to use the `Database` object inside of your `WorkerClass` object, you'll need to share that object with it. The `__construct` method will run when you first instantiate the object. So your code will looks something like this: `$db = new Database(); $worker = new WorkerClass($db);`. Now the Database object is saved inside of the `WorkerClass`, so you can access it like `$this->db`.

Comment: Thanks, as I understand it (Database $db) is copying the Database class into a new object called $db? This object is then assigned to the private variable with the same name?

Answer (score 1):

I've always created it in the `__constructor` and then used `$this->` to get at it.  This should work for your needs but I'd encourage you to play around with different styles and see what one works best.

I would NOT create a new object with `new` every time, unless you have a very good reason to.

Comment: The very good reason is usually found within tests, where you need an isolated environment each time. (This isn't the case though, so don't! :).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. How do you feel about @Truth 's method?

Comment: It looks good from here.  @Truth's got a lot more experience than I do.